# Inventory problem, only make receipts when stock is available

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an inventory stocking with Excel using VBA. I used this code if `sheet1` (`Receipt`) has an item from inventory then cut stock quantity from `sheet2` (`inventory`). But my problem is that even though the stock is already <0 it still can cut stock ( so i got - in my stock item). What I want is if the stock from inventory is 0 then you cannot make a receipt with that item else if the stock still available (>=1) then you can add that item to receipt.

Can anybody help me with this code?

So this is my code, I tried making the If Else statement but it doesn't work:

```
Sub printInvoice()
Sheet1.PrintPreview
'sheet1.printout
' we declare 4 variables
Dim rng1, rng2, cell1, cell2, cell3 As Range
Dim lastRow1 As Long
lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B16:B" & lastRow1)

Dim lastRow2 As Long
lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & lastRow2)

For Each cell1 In rng1
    If IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then Exit For
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For
                If cell1 = cell2 Then
                    If cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value < 1 Then
                        Debug.Print "Out Of Stock"
                        End If
                    Else
                     cell2.Offset(0, 1) = cell2.Offset(0, 1) - cell1.Offset(0, 1)
                End If
        Next cell2
Next cell1
End Sub
```

Comment: your if is ended before the calc. So needs to be `if out of stock show msg else subtract end if`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (I just changed your loops):

```
For Each cell1 In rng1
    If Not IsEmpty(cell1.Value) Then
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If cell1 = cell2 Then
                If cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value < 1 Then
                    Debug.Print "Out Of Stock"
                    End If
                Else
                    cell2.Offset(0, 1) = cell2.Offset(0, 1) - cell1.Offset(0, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next cell2
    End If
Next cell1
```

The thing is that you prematurely exit for loop with `Exit For` statements. I.e. when first cell in first sheet is empty, you quit the loop and don't do anything else. I also removed second `Exit For` as well.

Comment: Why `End If` in the last if?  No need for it is there?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Only if it is in one line. I have spread this statement over multiple lines, that's why.

Comment: it runs but it does nothing, i can still print the receipt.. do you know why ?

Answer (score -1):

Your if is ended before the calc. So needs to be

```
   if out of stock 
        show msg  
   else 
        subtract 
   end if
```

like so..

```
If cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value < 1 Then
      Debug.Print "Out Of Stock"
Else
      cell2.Offset(0, 1) = cell2.Offset(0, 1) - cell1.Offset(0, 1)
End If
```